# can't log into a site build using civibuild

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

This is how I created my site

```
civibuild create demo8 \
 --type drupal-clean \
 --web-root /sites/demo8 \
 --title demo8 \
 --url http://demo8.roiaws.com \
 --admin-user admin --admin-pass 12345
```

and this is what I get after I try to log on using admin/12345 or demo/demo (in short - it doesn't login):

[image]
Additional info: when looking for problems in the civibuild output, this is the only interesting thing I saw:

```
+ pushd /sites/demo8/sites/all/modules/civicrm/./bin/..
/sites/demo8/sites/all/modules/civicrm /sites/demo8/sites/all/modules/civicrm
+ php bin/cli.php -e System -a flush --triggers 1 --session 1
Failed to bootstrap CMS
Died during initialization+ mysql -udemo8civi_k31lr -poNammLP06izIxkcx -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306 demo8civi_k31lr -e 'UPDATE civicrm_domain SET config_backend = NULL; UPDATE civicrm_setting SET value = NULL WHERE name = '\''userFrameworkResourceURL'\'';'
+ popd
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When setting up a new environment, sometimes Apache's mod_rewrite is disabled. This breaks in Drupal -- creating a symptom where the home page opens, but logins do nothing. Try enabling mod_rewrite.

I've filed an issue about this: https://github.com/totten/amp/issues/23